# How to get a public access url of a object from gcp after uploading a object in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, image, google-cloud-platform, upload, flask-restful

I'm able to upload a image file on gcp in python, but I'm not able to get a url to access the image from gcp, I have tried couple of options but none of them are working!!

here's the code of what i have tried

```py
def UploadToBucket():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            binary_data = request.data  # This contains the binary image data
            filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
            # Upload the file to the Google Cloud Storage bucket
            bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
            blob = bucket.blob(filename)
            blob.upload_from_string(binary_data)
            uploaded_url = blob.public_url
            filename_pattern = r'filename="(.+)"'
            match = re.search(filename_pattern, binary_data.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
            if match:
                filename = match.group(1)
                # Now 'filename' contains the name of the uploaded file.
            # expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3650)  # 3650 days = approximately 10 years
            # uploaded_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=expiration)  # This URL will effectively not expire for a very long time
            return {
                       "data": {
                           "success": True,
                           "message": 'File uploaded successfully',
                           "file_name": filename,
                           "url": uploaded_url
                       }
                   }, 200
        except Exception as e:
            return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
```

also i have tried doing this:

```py
expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3650)  # 3650 days = approximately 10 years
uploaded_url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=expiration)  # This URL will effectively not expire for a very long time
```

Comment: Heads up, for blocks of code you can use three backticks (`) instead of one. Usually you would use one just for a single line of code (I also use it for class and function names)

Comment: Thank you!! I wasn't knowing it, this is my first time asking a question on this platform!!!

Comment: No problem, if you check now the **also i have tried doing this** seems part of the code, that's because the backticks should be on their own line.

Comment: It seems you need `blob.make_public()` before `uploaded_url = blob.public_url`.

Comment: Im getting this error when i click on the url. 
 
 <Error> <Code>AccessDenied</Code> <Message>Access denied.</Message> <Details> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist). </Details> </Error>

Comment: Google Cloud Storage has different [endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints) for different types of access. Your post does not describe your objective (public, signed-url, authenticated, etc.).